# angular2 AoT error Function calls are not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-aot

When I use angular2 AoT, I get an error:

```
 Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 54:17 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol COMPILER_PROVIDERS in
```

and in my Directive Module, I have code like this:

```
import { COMPILER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/compiler';
@NgModule({
/*imports ...*/
providers: [
    COMPILER_PROVIDERS,
]
})
```

I understand that I should change the **COMPILER_PROVIDERS** to an exported function, But when I check the source code of @angular/compiler, I find this:

```
export declare const COMPILER_PROVIDERS: Array<any | Type<any> | {
    [k: string]: any;
} | any[]>;

export declare class RuntimeCompilerFactory implements CompilerFactory {
    private _defaultOptions;
    constructor(defaultOptions: CompilerOptions[]);
    createCompiler(options?: CompilerOptions[]): Compiler;
}
```

I don't know how the COMPILER_PROVIDERS works, and I don't know how to transfer it to a  exported function in my module.

Comment: Having the same problem and could not yet find a solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to not use `COMPILER_PROVIDERS` any more. Also, you do not need to include `JitCompiler` in your list of providers.

Instead, use `JitCompilerFactory` from "@angular/compiler". It is not injectable, so just create a new instance of it yourself like this:

```
private compiler: Compiler = new JitCompilerFactory([{useDebug: false, useJit: true}]).createCompiler();
```

The rest works as before, for example following Radim Kohler's excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian, that really helped me!

Comment: Anyone have working JitCompiletFactory with AOT sample ? When I am using it I'am always getting No NgModule metadata found for DynamicHtmlModule

Comment: Just wanted to add that the shown Compiler comes from @angular/core, not @angular/compiler like the previous JitCompiler and the factory. Took me a while to find it.

Comment: I removed `COMPILER_PROVIDERS` and implemented `JitCompilerFactory`. But that took me while to notice @Tarmo's comment. And yes It starts working for me like a charm. Need to include `Compiler` from `@angular/core`.